# Ignore DNS from DHCP server in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I set static `DNS` in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

But my PC still obtains DNS from DHCP, this is my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 192.168.100.2 
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

How to ignore obtained `DNS` from `DHCP` server?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can add this line to your `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

Then restart network or run `dhclient` to make changes.

From `man dhclient.conf`:

```
The supersede statement

       supersede [ option declaration ];

       If for some option the client should always  use  a  locally-configured
       value  or  values rather than whatever is supplied by the server, these
       values can be defined in the supersede statement.
```

Comment: Also you can comment out in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` in `request` parameters that you don't want to request, for DNS it can be `domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search`.

Comment: @Alex I've noticed that some devices respond with options you didn't ask for. While you would think it would be ignored if not requested, the opposite appears true in practice: options returned unasked for are actually processed. Something to remember when configuring security sensitive devices... (e.g. send CIDR routes and bypasses traffic from the gateway.)

Answer (score -1):

Drop a script in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d` with this:

```
make_resolv_conf() { : ; }
```

Make it executable. Done. This is the only 100% sure-fire way I have found to keep dhclient from clobbering resolv.conf, apart from making resolv.conf immutable.