# How to disable a specific interface (dhclient) from resolvconf?

Tags: resolv.conf, vagrant, dhclient, resolvconf

I am using `ubuntu/trusty64` Vagrant box with VirtualBox. I want to permanently disable `nameserver 10.0.2.3` set by `resolvconf` based on Vagrant's default `eth0` interface.

I have a network defined in my `Vagrantfile` as follows:

```
server.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp", virtualbox__intnet: true
```

This creates an interface `eth1` with DHCP-pulled settings. The `resolv.conf` looks like this:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.0.2.3
nameserver 10.20.30.40
search local
```

- `nameserver 10.0.2.3` and `search local` come from from DHCP settings on `eth0`
- `nameserver 10.20.30.40` comes from from DHCP settings on `eth1`

I want to retain the latter (10.20.30.40), while disabling settings coming from the `eth0`. I can remove it temporarily using `resolvconf -d eth0.dhclient`, but the settings keep reappearing after reboot.

I know I can override all DHCP DNS settings with a static one as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136117/ignore-dns-from-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu), however I want to retain DHCP settings from `eth1` interface and disable only `eth0`.

I tried editing `/etc/resolvconf/interface-order` and changed `eth*` to `eth1` to no avail.

Is there a way without editing the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf` script?

Answer (score 2):

It is because Vagrant gives IP address to eth0 interface and the default setting is via DHCP. So if you want to do it with some patching here is the answer. All you need to do is edit your /etc/network/interfaces file by

`nano /etc/network/interfaces`

and add `post-up resolvconf -d eth0.dhclient` line after `iface eth1 inet dhcp`

so your `/etc/network/interfaces` would look like this

`

```
 # This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Source interfaces
# Please check /etc/network/interfaces.d before changing this file
# as interfaces may have been defined in /etc/network/interfaces.d
# NOTE: the primary ethernet device is defined in
# /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
# See LP: #1262951
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*.cfg

#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
    post-up resolvconf -d eth0.dhclient
#VAGRANT-END`
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options: to write protect your resolv.conf, change the dhclient code and disable auto-update on the nameservers, or disable the DNS from the eth0.

**Option 1:** Write protecting /etc/resolv.conf file:

```
$ chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

The +i option (attribute) write protects /etc/resolv.conf file on Linux so that no one can modify it including root user.

**Option 2:** dhclient-script hooks

Open the "resolvconf" file in dhclient folder:

```
$ nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient-enter-hooks.d/resolvconf
```

and change the code to:

```
make_resolv_conf(){
    :
}
```

Above script will replace make_resolv_conf() with our own function. This functions does nothing.

**Option 3:**

Open your ifcfg file:

```
$ nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

and change the PEERDNS option to No:

```
PEERDNS=no
```

**Bonus:** This will not override your resolv.conf file or disable the DNS update, but will overwrite your route table. When you send some DNS request no matter what is the content in your resolv.conf file it check your route table and send the request to specific address:

```
$ ip route add 8.8.8.8/32 via 192.168.1.1
```