# How do I stop Debian from overwriting /etc/resolv.conf and overwriting my VPN's nameservers?

Tags: debian, openvpn, resolv.conf

#### Background

I'm running Debian stretch/stable; I installed openvpn from the repo abd downloaded the configuration file `us1041.conf` (as an example) from my VPN provider into `/etc/openvpn/us1041.conf`. I want openvpn to run at boot, so following the VPN provider's instructions, I created `/etc/openvpn/auth.txt` with my credentials, add `auth-user-pass auth.txt` to the configuration file, and added `AUTOSTART="us1041"` to `/etc/default/openvpn`.

If I manually add the nameservers to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 78.46.223.24
nameserver 162.242.211.137
```

the VPN works. Great! However, once I reboot, `/etc/resolv.conf` is overwritten with the nameservers from my ISP, and no connections resolve.

Also, I'm not using network manager or any GUI app to configure the network. I didn't install a graphical interface and network configuration worked "out of the box." This is `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

#### Question

I think I need to use the [`/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf` script](https://github.com/masterkorp/openvpn-update-resolv-conf), but I'm not sure how to configure that with the configuration files that came from my VPN provider.

How can I get the VPN's nameservers to persist across reboots?

Comment: The Debian people have been trying for some while to write [a wiki page about these very interactions over `resolv.conf`](https://wiki.debian.org/resolv.conf).

Comment: see https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/OpenVPN#DNS

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/resolv.conf. My preferred way is a bit aggressive: `chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible solutions

#### [Override DNS servers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136117/ignore-dns-from-dhcp-server-in-ubuntu) from from your ISP's DHCP server:

*/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf*:

```
supersede domain-name-servers 78.46.223.24, 162.242.211.137
```

---

#### Edit `/etc/network/interfaces` *(or are you using NetworkManager?)*

Include `dns-nameservers 78.46.223.24 162.242.211.137` along with your internet interface's definitions (ip, gateway, *etc.*) if you define them there.

---

#### Edit your `NetworkManager` configuration

Using the `nm-connection-editor` or `nmcli`, for example, specify DNS servers manually.

---

#### Use a [helper script](https://github.com/jonathanio/update-systemd-resolved)

Integrate OpenVPN with `systemd-resolved` via DBus, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The first 2 lines of `/etc/resolv.conf` is

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

I think you didn't read it...

You have 2 choices:
 - put these lines into your openvpn.conf (the preferred way)

```
dhcp-option DNS 78.46.223.24
dhcp-option DNS 162.242.211.137
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

or these to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` (can cause problems when vpn is down)

```
nameserver 78.46.223.24
nameserver 162.242.211.137
```

Comment: The first two lines of said file aren't what you claim they are.  At least not always.  My resolv.conf was updated (trashed) by I think dhclient, and the only line is a nameserver entry…
Not everyone uses (or used in 2017) resolvconf.  I tried it shortly after it was introduced, and soon found it *very* lacking and never used it again.